# NVIDIA gpu not working together with amd cpu with integrated graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I've recently bought a new laptop (omen by HP valkyrie R7) with following issue-relevant specs:

- AMD Ryzen 7 4800H Processor
- Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 6GB
- 15.6 FHD Antiglare ultraslim IPS 144Hz Narrow Border (main screen)
- Ubuntu LTS 20.04 with nvidia-driver-440 installed (recommended)

I tried all of the current things with one screen, the plan is to hook up another screen though.

Concretely, the issue is that my nvidia card is not being used at all, instead my laptop's integrated graphics get all the work.
I've been looking for a solution for over a week now across many platforms, nothing really helped.

**Extra information:**

1. nvidia-settings returns "ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system" and launches an empty box.
   I have fixed this issue with a simple xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/ containing this (graphics still wasn't being used though):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
  Identifier "layout"
  Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection
```

2. when I run nvidia-xconfig, it creates a xorg.conf file, looking valid. It does warn me package xorg-server wasn't found though. (when I tried to apt-get xorg-server it told me it couldn't find such a package, even though it autocompleted).
   Anyhoo, the xorg.conf file gets made, I reboot and I get a black screen with a blinking cursor right before the login screen. (this is fixed by deleting the xorg.conf)
3. I tried using software for this like system76, but it didnt really work either, I was able to switch settings, but when I rebooted, it resulted in the same black screen with a blinking cursor. Using the cli version of system76 to revert the settings resolved that.

I have tried many things, did a lot of clean installs to try again, but nothing really worked. If I need to provide any extra information please tell me and I will leave it here.

Thanks in adance!

Comment: Are you *sure* that it's not being used?  Your device has what is called "hybrid graphics". This is the monster you're working with.  If you have trouble, you should research topics using that term

Comment: @Nmath Ive spent a while looking for that, but all I could find was guides for an intel-nvidia or intel-amd setup. 
I found a generic one, but that one requires me to use nouveau drivers, which also results in a blank screen.

Comment: I'm thinking you might need the 450 driver from Nvidia for that card. I have had issues in the past with discrete Nvidia cards if Ubuntu was installed using nouveau and then later switched to proprietary drivers. You might also want to look up HWE (hardware enablement) which can help add compatibility for new devices - most of your specs are hardware that is relatively new

Comment: Using the newest drivers (450) resulted in nvidia-settings working again, and `nvidia-smi` tells me my graphics card has 11/6000mb used, so it's definitely progress. I tested with a game though, and it doesn't seem to be using the card, but Ill test a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue, for anyone with the same problem, Ill try listing everything I did.

I started off with a clean ubuntu 20.04 LTS install, first thing I did was update my drivers to the `nvidia-driver-450` package, instead of the recommended `nvidia-driver-440`. This fixed `nvidia-settings`.

Then I followed the first steps of the answer posted on [this page](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/2) by generix. As soon as he started creating optimus.desktop files I stopped following and tested right ahead.

You can open a terminal, run this command to test it:
`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo | grep vendor`
if it returns NVIDIA corp, you're in the clear.

Now whenever you want to launch an application using your nvidia card, you have to set those two environment variables.
For steam games, just do:
`__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia %command%`
in your games launch options (right click game -> properties -> set launch options).

I tested with ark, and it worked fine. If it still doesn't work, I wish you good luck on your search for your answer.